# getting paypal "client id" in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I followed the instructions to embed paypal into my app. but I couldn't find the client id. I don't know how it looks like!!
can anyone please explain it to me? I didn't understand from their website.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps and then log in with your PayPal account.